# How to set parameter for all of the methods in Inherited class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, python-requests

I am currently learning Object Oriented Programming in Python. I have some issues with understanding how to pass to all methods that I inherite from Parten class. I will show you example of code.

Below you can see my Parent class (it's simple api wrapper).

```
class AlphaVantageClient:

    _URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?"

    def __init__(self, api_key=None):
        self.__api_key = api_key

    def show_base_url(self):
        print(self._URL)

    def set_api_key(self, api_key: str):
        self.__api_key = api_key

    def __call_api(self, query_parameters: dict,**kwargs):
        """
        The structure looks like:
            co./query?function{}&symbol{}
        :param query_parameters:
        :return: response
        """
        query_parameters["apikey"] = self.__api_key

        response = requests.get(
            AlphaVantageClient._URL,
            params=query_parameters,
            proxies=self.__proxy
        )

        validate_http_status(response)
        return response.json()

    def company_overview(self, ticker: str, **kwargs):
        query_parameters = {
            "function": "OVERVIEW",
            "symbol": ticker
        }
        return self.__call_api(query_parameters, **kwargs)

    def balance_sheet(self, ticker: str, **kwargs):
        query_parameters = {
            "function": "BALANCE_SHEET",
            "symbol": ticker
        }
        return self.__call_api(query_parameters, **kwargs)

    def income_statement(self, ticker: str, **kwargs):
        query_parameters = {
            "function": "INCOME_STATEMENT",
            "symbol": ticker
        }
        return self.__call_api(query_parameters, **kwargs)

    def cash_flow(self, ticker: str, **kwargs):
        query_parameters = {
            "function": "CASH_FLOW",
            "symbol": ticker
        }
        return self.__call_api(query_parameters, **kwargs)
```

And below there is my child class in which I want to inheritate from `AlphaVantageClient` class all of the methods.

```
class Stock(AlphaVantageClient):
    def __init__(self, ticker: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.client = AlphaVantageClient()

    def set_api_key(self, api_key):
        self.client.set_api_key(api_key)
```

But my problem is that as you see in `AlphaVantegeClient` all of my methods has parameter `symbol`, I would like to set in one line or something like that for all of the methods to have my `symbol` parameter set to `self.ticker` from `Stock` class. Is it possible to do that ? Or I need to somehow refactor Parent class code ?

Comment: So accept `ticker` in `AlphaVantageClient.__init__` and store it as `self.ticker`, just like you are doing with `self.__api_key`

Comment: And you can give default values to the symbol parameter based on `self.ticker`

Comment: Guys, can you look on my answer below. I think that
we did not understand each other, or I just don't know how to implement your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how inheritance works. When you create a class `Stock` that subclasses (inherits from) class `AlphaVantageClient` it automatically gets all of the attributes and methods of that parent class as if you defined them as part of the new subclass.

You should absolutely not have this line in the init: `self.client = AlphaVantageClient()`. By subclassing (inheriting) from `AlphaVantageClient` it already is an instance of `AlphaVantageClient` and that creates a separate additional instance of and `AlphaVantageClient` separate from the one it is.

In your `Stock` class you do not have to redefine `set_api_key()` unless you are trying to change it for some reason and you are not. This method is just trying to save the `api_key` into an internal class attribute and it already does that so just leave it out/un-redefined in `Stock`.

You do not need to rework `AlphaVantageClient`, but you do need to have stubs in `Stock` since they need to substitute in the saved `ticker` parameter into the calls to the parent. Like this:

```py
class Stock(AlphaVantageClient):
    def __init__(self, ticker: str, api_key=None):
        super().__init__(api_key)
        self.ticker = ticker
        
    def company_overview(self, **kwargs):
        return super().company_overview(self.ticker, **kwargs)

    def balance_sheet(self, **kwargs):
        return super().balance_sheet(self.ticker, **kwargs)

    def income_statement(self, **kwargs):
        return super().income_statement(self.ticker, **kwargs)

    def cash_flow(self, **kwargs):
        return super().cash_flow(self.ticker, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You just clarified many of  unknowns that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answer. I don't know if I get it correctly.

```
class AlphaVantageClient:

    _URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?"

    def __init__(self, api_key=None, symbol=None):
        self.__api_key = api_key
        self.__proxy = {}
        self.__validate_api_key()
        self.__data_type = 'json'
        self.__symbol = symbol

    def set_api_key(self, api_key: str):
        self.__api_key = api_key

    def __call_api(self, query_parameters: dict,**kwargs):
        """
        The structure looks like:
            co./query?function{}&symbol{}
        :param query_parameters:
        :return: response
        """
        query_parameters["apikey"] = self.__api_key

        response = requests.get(
            AlphaVantageClient._URL,
            params=query_parameters,
            proxies=self.__proxy
        )

        validate_http_status(response)
        return response.json()

    def company_overview(self, symbol: str, **kwargs):
        query_parameters = {
            "function": "OVERVIEW",
            "symbol": symbol
        }
        return self.__call_api(query_parameters, **kwargs)

    def balance_sheet(self, symbol: str, **kwargs):
        query_parameters = {
            "function": "BALANCE_SHEET",
            "symbol": symbol
        }
        return self.__call_api(query_parameters, **kwargs)

    def income_statement(self, symbol: str, **kwargs):
        query_parameters = {
            "function": "INCOME_STATEMENT",
            "symbol": symbol
        }
        return self.__call_api(query_parameters, **kwargs)

    def cash_flow(self, symbol: str, **kwargs):
        query_parameters = {
            "function": "CASH_FLOW",
            "symbol": symbol
        }
        return self.__call_api(query_parameters, **kwargs)

class Stock(AlphaVantageClient):
    def __init__(self, symbol: str):
        super().__init__(symbol)
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.client = AlphaVantageClient(symbol)

    def set_api_key(self, api_key):
        self.client.set_api_key(api_key)
```

Now my classes look like this. And I try to create instance of my class and call one of methods like below:

```
from client import AlphaVantageClient, Stock

stock = Stock(symbol="FB")
stock.income_statement()
```

And I get an error:

```
tests\test_client.py:5: in <module>
    stock.income_statement()
E   TypeError: income_statement() missing 1 required positional argument: 'symbol'
```

So I don't know if I don't understand you correctly or I just explained my problem in wrong way. So I will try once more:

If I call my `AlphaVantageClient`, I want to use it in the way that I create instance of that class and I call methods providing as an parameter symbol of stock e.g

```
client = AlphaVantageClient()
income_statement = client.income_statement(symbol="FB")
```

But if I create a `Stock` class I would like to have symbol stored in class and don't need to provide it as a paramtere in my methods: All the methods should use that symbol that I provided when I created `Stock` class as default. So the usage should look like below:

```
stock = Stock(symbol="FB")
income_statement = stock.income_statement()
```

And this way I will fetch the data for "FB" in all of my methods.

Is it possible ? If yes, can you explain me little more how to achive it.